# Create and access frozenset with Boost Python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have some C++ methods that have `std::set<std::string>` as argument or return value.
I would like to map this to a Python `frozenset` (or regular `set`) but there does not seem to be a straightforward way to do this.
Does anyone know how one may accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard `indexing_suite` from Boost.Python does not support `std::set`. There is a indexing_suite v2, that works on all stl containers. (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-July/014704.html)

It may not have made it to the official distribution, but you can find it by asking around. 
(http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2009-July/014691.html)

I found it to be harder to use then the original `indexing_suite`, but it might fit your needs.

If that does not work, you can just manually wrap `std::set<std::string>` like you would any other class. This will get you a `std::set<std::string>` into python, where you can turn it into a python `set` fairly easily.

---

I think that both of those are more work then is called for though. Here is what I would do:

First, wrap the function in C++ with one that has the same signature, but stuffs the returned data in to a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `std::set<std::string>`. expose that function rather then the original

Now you have the data in python.

Second, wrap the c++ function in python function that takes the data in that `std::vector<std::string>` and stuffs it into a python `set`.

Yes, this is rather silly from a design aesthetics point of view, and not the most performant code in the world, but is gets you to where you are going with a minimum of code, and it is fairly robust.

Comment: The second option is what I currently do, but it isn't really nice and clean though... I may give indexing suite version 2 a try.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `std::map<YourType, int>` instead of `std::set<YourType>`, the value can be for example 0. std::map has the same insert/search time complexity as std::set, it also keeps the keys ordered, it will only bloat the memory a little. Then you can use map indexing suite and in python you can hide the difference in some wrapper class if needed. The disanvantage is that you have to modify your existing c++ code a little bit.